# Do rewards double if one pray twice in congregation?

Tags: salat, jamaat, reward

If I pray twice in two different mosques, will I double the rewards twice?
For example, I pray fajr in a mosque and walk to another one close by with a slightly different prayer time to pray in that other one too.
Will I get the full hassanates for both prayers?

Comment: When an amount is mentioned in Arabic then the meaning is to emphasize something you cannot calculate your reward as you don't even know whether any of your two prayers was accepted by Allah in first place.

Comment: https://www.islamweb.net/ar/fatwa/41889/

Answer (score 1):

**Not really, but you will get rewarded.**
Generally, we go to the congregation to offer obligatory prayer, or fardh salah. When you pray for the second time, it becomes a voluntary prayer. And as you know, voluntary prayer (nafl) is not as important as obligatory (fardh) prayer. So, the reward for praying fardh and nafl is not the same.
Here is why praying Fardh (obligatory) for the second time becomes nafl(voluntary):

> Jabir bin Yazid bin Al-Aswad Al Amir told us that his father said:
> "I attended Fajr prayer with the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ)in Masjid Al Khaif. When he finished praying, he saw two men at the back of the people who had not prayed with him. He said: 'Bring them here.' So they were brought to him, trembling. He said: 'What kept you from praying with us? They said: '0 Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) we has already prayed in our lodgings.'He said: 'Do not do that. **If you have already prayed in your lodgings, then you come to a mosque in which there is a congregation, then pray with them, and it will be a voluntary prayer for you.**"'
>
> [Sunan an-Nasa'i ,  كتاب الإمامة , باب إعادة الفجر مع الجماعة لمن صلى وحده](https://sunnah.com/nasai:858)

*But don't pray Fazr or Asr twice as praying nafl is not liked after those prayers (Fazr and Asr).*

Comment: I suppose this hadith was translated by you it would be helpful if at least you'd add a source of it.

Comment: Note that there is difference among the madhabs on whether this applies when the first prayer was also in a congregation.

Answer (score 1):

The Prophet, may God bless him and grant him peace, forbade the obligatory prayer to be repeated twice in a day. He says: Do not pray twice in a day. Narrated by Abu Dawood (579).

This prohibition applies only to the one who intends the second prayer to be an obligatory prayer (fardh), but if he intends to perform a voluntary prayer(nafl), then there is nothing wrong with that.

Answer (score -1):

In a hadith it mentions the reward is 27x more rewardful than praying alone.

Abdullāh ibn ‘Umar (may Allah be pleased with him) reported that the Messenger (may Allah's peace and blessings be upon him) said: "Praying in congregation is twenty-seven degrees better than praying alone."

Sahih/Authentic. - [Al-Bukhari and Muslim]

Edit:

The first will give you full reward but after that the second time you pray fajr that will count as a nawafil. And Prophet Muhammad Sallahu Aliehe Wassallam told us NOT to pray nawafils after fajr.
“Do not perform prayers when the sun rises and when it sets. For, the sun rises between the two horns of the devil and sets between the two horns of the devil." (Haythami, Majmauz-Zawaid, 2/255)

“Pray Fajr, then refrain from praying until the sun has risen and become high”.